# How can I find the end date of the calendar control in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

This calendar has a date range of 11 days from the current date, how can I check if the date that is entered through the script is between this range and select it else if that entered date mentioned in script not in that date range then current date should be clicked.

There is a class that can be used to get the current date (class="owl-dt-calendar-cell-content owl-dt-calendar-cell-today")[calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcSsA.png)

```
public void selectRequiredOn(String date)
{
    requiredOnClick.click();
    currentDate.getText();
    
    if(currentDate.equals(date))
    {
        currentDate.click();
    }
```

Comment: Didn’t you just ask this question yesterday or the date before? Did you delete it and asked again? Sorry, I don’t know Selenium, so don’t understand the question and cannot answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void selectRequiredOn(String date) throws InterruptedException
    {
        requiredOnClick.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        WebElement calendarRange = createWebElement("//table[@class='owl-dt-calendar-table owl-dt-calendar-month-table']//td[not(contains(@class,' owl-dt-calendar-cell-disabled ng-star-inserted'))]//span[contains(text(),'"+date+"')]");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        try
        {
        if(calendarRange.isDisplayed())
        {       
            calendarRange.click();
//          WebElement dateClick = createWebElement("//table[@class='owl-dt-calendar-table owl-dt-calendar-month-table']//td[not(contains(@class,' owl-dt-calendar-cell-disabled ng-star-inserted'))]//span[contains(text(),'"+date+"')]");
//          dateClick.click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            calendarSetButtonClick.click();     
        }
        else
        {
            currentDate.click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            calendarSetButtonClick.click();
        }
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).